# Find a replace dynamic string in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a tool to migrate content from a SiteFinity Website to Wordpress. One of the challenges I'm having is handling instances where the html content stored in the MSSQL database has SiteFinity's versions of shortcodes. View an example of content with the shortcode below for an idea:

```
<div class="image_boxR"> 
    <div style="text-align: left;">
        <img src="[images]8483f3a8-d18b-48ed-80f7-a60c26469132" title="The title of the image" /><br /> 
    </div> 
    <div>
        This is the caption for the image.
    </div> 
</div>
```

I've found a few posts where a similar question is asked however the entire string is known whereas with my current situation, the string I need to "grab" is `[images]8483f3a8-d18b-48ed-80f7-a60c26469132` where `[images]` is what I need to look for and I need to store each GUID (`8483f3a8-d18b-48ed-80f7-a60c26469132`) in an array that I will then use to query another table and get the correct image URL.

So, finding the `[images]` seems simple enough, the question is, how do I extract the 36 characters following the `[images]` tag?

Comment: using function : str_replace .

Comment: Thank you, I considered that, how would I handle the 36 characters after the string? Those are not known

Comment: make filter to achieve this functionality.

Comment: you can use `ltrim` also : https://eval.in/715373

Comment: $filter = '[images]';
$str = 'http://www.domain.com/images/';

$array = array(
'[images]8483f3a8-d18b-48ed-80f7-a60c26469132',
'[images]8483f3a8-d18b-48ed-80f7-a60c26469132'
);

foreach($array as $value)
{
 $bodytag = str_replace($filter, $str, $value);
}

Comment: @Daniel please try my Shortcode library: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . If you need any help, please create an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest way is to use regular expressions.
Take a look at preg_match_all and preg_replace functions.
For matching this shortcodes use this regexp `#\[images\](?<guid>[a-f0-9\-]*)#` (online regexp tester https://regex101.com/r/FZuJPh/1 )

Example code for getting matches:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

$string = <<<EOF
<div class="image_boxR"> 
    <div style="text-align: left;">
        <img src="[images]8483f3a8-d18b-48ed-80f7-a60c26469132" title="The title of the image" /><br /> 
    </div> 
    <div>
        This is the caption for the image.
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="image_boxR"> 
    <div style="text-align: left;">
        <img src="[images]8483f3a8-d18b-48ed-80f7-a60c26469132" title="The title of the image" /><br /> 
    </div> 
    <div>
        This is the caption for the image.
    </div> 
</div>
EOF;

preg_match_all("/\[images\](?<guid>[a-f0-9\-]*)/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: This looks like it'll work, I'm just testing in a real scenario

Comment: I'm struggling to handle the array, it's returning an array with three items in it for each unique GUID, can't it be cleaner? $matches returns `array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(44) "[images]1f9cb19e-361b-4714-b5e9-5010d3322f6f" } ["guid"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "1f9cb19e-361b-4714-b5e9-5010d3322f6f" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "1f9cb19e-361b-4714-b5e9-5010d3322f6f" } } `

Comment: Just iterate over $result['guid'] or what you need

Answer (score 1):

If the text is pretty much in the same format, this should do the trick?

```
$content =<<<EOF
<div class="image_boxR"> 
    <div style="text-align: left;">
        <img src="[images]8483f3a8-d18b-48ed-80f7-a60c26469132" title="The title of the image" /><br /> 
    </div> 
    <div>
        This is the caption for the image.
    </div> 
</div>
EOF;

preg_match('/"\[images\](.*?)"/', $content, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Not sure who did that Lionel

Comment: If it's only one occurrence, use `preg_match`. If multiple, occurrence, use `preg_match_all`. My regex is probably too broad in your case, hence the downvote. It works too, just maybe slower in a few microseconds :)

Comment: Yes, that and, I'm not sure what "dd" is, thank you in any event!

Comment: oops sorry that's laravel's `dd` function to print and die. So sorry to accidentally included that.

Comment: Thanks Lionel, to be fair the answer above is more complete.

Comment: no worries! Feel free to accept any answer you like